# Yii CDbTestCase findByAttributes is creating a row

Tags: php, model, yii, phpunit

I am writing a unit test, and I stumbled upon a very strange behavior.

I have a test fixture so I expect to see 1 row in the database (there is only 1 row listed in the fixture) I wrote some code to run a findByAttributes as follows:

```
$client_id = 6;
$unique = array (
    "client_id" => (String) $client_id,
    "id" => "2" //I have a fixture that uses id 1
);

$model = Agent::model()->findByAttributes($unique);
die();
```

When I have this configuration after my test runs and the die is hit, I see 2 rows in the database. However if I do:

```
$client_id = 6;
$unique = array (
    "client_id" => (String) $client_id,
    "id" => "2" //I have a fixture that uses id 1
);

die();
$model = Agent::model()->findByAttributes($unique);
//NOTE: I only moved the die() above the findByAttributes.
```

I see only the 1 row from my fixture. Why is findByAttributes creating a row in my test DB?

Comment: What happens when you do not specify an 'id'? I would imagine it has something to do with that, but I can't run any tests right now. Either way this shouldn't be inserting any records in your DB. Is there any other code, fixtures, or tests you are running at the same time as this code?

Comment: No difference, I get the exact same behavior.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your tests for this CDbTestCase? I don't think this is the problem. EDIT: Just saw your last bit about moving the die() statement. I see no reason why this model would insert a record. What's the contents of $model after it inserts a record?

Comment: Also this is just a standard Yii model, no fancy stuff.

Comment: $model is a valid "Agent" Yii model with default values from the database other than the $unique criteria from the code above.

Comment: There is really no reason for that. $model should be an empty array, especially with your id specification. Maybe use CDbCriteria / Agent::model()->find($criteria)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agent is a singleton model in my system. I guess I am doing something fancy.

Clearly a Singleton is going to create itself if one does not exist. Doh!